# Getting path of file in error handling - python

Tags: python, error-handling

Is there any way I can get the path of an input file if the value error or key error raises.
for example, I have an excel file as input. I am require to merge the column of the excel file with other excel file(second input). If one of the column in the first excel input file gone, key error raise. Is there anyway I can get the path of the first input excel file when key error raise?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're asking because if there is an error your program just errors out? If thats the case you can handle these errors and have your program continue after erroring with a try except statement as such.

```py
try:
  ... 
except:
  ...
```

see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp) for more info.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thank you for your respond. Actually I want to show user the file that have problem in the try except. When the key error raise, I would like to get the files that have problem and show it to the user.

Comment: I think you'd have to then check for where the error occurred after catching it. If you're trying to merge two files and it fails you could then perform additional checks for misaligned columns and return which side has the issue. You're above example, would be trivial. try: >>> my_zip_file.getinfo('Batman') >>> except: >>> print('Error, avengers.zip...')